# Did anyone propose switching back to using date honey on Rosh-Hashanah to dip apples?

Tags: minhag, eretz-yisrael, rosh-hashanah-new-year

As seen from ["why-use-bee-honey-on-rosh-hashana"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/why-use-bee-honey-on-rosh-hashana), the use of bee honey in the minhag is clearly circumstantial - the lack of "the original" honey led to use its substitute - bee honey.

Some background: the Land of Israel is known/blessed with "milk and honey", where honey refers specifically to dates (earliest I can find is [Mishna Bikurim 1.3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.8.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Bikkurim&lang2=en)) but see also [Yerushalmi Bikurim 2b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.2b.3?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> **ודבש אלו התמרים**. יכול דבש ממש? רבי תנחומא בשם רבי יצחק ב"ר לעזר כתיב (דברי הימים ב ל״א:ה׳) וכפרוץ הדבר הרבו בני ישראל ראשית דגן תירוש ויצהר ודבש. ודבש חייב במעשרות. אלא אלו התמרים שהן חייבין במעשרות.

Once we have plenty of the original date honey, did anybody offer/switch to using date honey to signify and remember the honor of Eretz Israel (maybe a sort of "Leshana Haba'ah B'Yirushalayim")?

Comment: My wife's grandfather zt"l dipped a date in honey, instead an apple, so it will be honey-within-honey of a year.

Comment: Who said the honey for the apple has anything to do with the honey of the Torah? (Also Ramma never said to dip, just sweetened with. The writers of the song took some liberties, apparently)