# Can I use grapes honey (Dabas) in Rosh Hashana?

Tags: minhag, food, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Following [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/why-use-bee-honey-on-rosh-hashana) question. Can I use [grapes honey](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape_honey) (Dabas/Dibas) as honey in Rosh Hashana? As can be seen in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8MRDzV41QI) video. It seems that it was the most ancient and popular honey in Israel. In addition, it is one of the seven species of the land of Israel. In addition, the Arabs call the grapes honey Dabas or Dibas, which is the Hebrew equivalence to honey. I would like to know if there are any Jewish sources for the usage of grape honey as the original honey in Israel? In addition, I would like to know if [Carob honey](https://www.honeytraveler.com/single-flower-honey/carob-honey/) can be used as honey in Rosh Hashana, as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I use"? Are you asking about its efficacy in fulfilling a particular mitzvah (and if so, what mitzvah) or whether traditions exist making it precedented. https://outorah.org/p/5705/

Comment: Was date honey not more popular?

Comment: The main point of honey is that it is sweet.

Comment: Comment for now, until I can locate the Talmud source for "simanim" (signs). These are all minhag (custom) - things like eating carrots, beets, and dipping apple in honey. I am uncertain if apple is among the simanim mentioned in the Talmud, and, if not, there is no mention of honey, anyway.  If dipping apple in honey is a siman, it doesn't matter what type of honey you use. As far as I know, it doesn't have to be bee's honey.